# Disable pager on Mapview

Tags: android

Hi actually i am using share lock lib and a tab host in my project.
i give a concept of pager in tab so user can swipe tab fragment.

i have a problem. actually in my last fragment i use a map view and a list View. concept is that i show multiple markers on map and will display on list view.

so when user start  horizontal scrolling on map view pager will take next or previous fragment (Screen).

how can i manage it. i want that pager work on only list view Not on my map view. 
i hope u wil be understand my problem. How can i do this
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're trying to do, and what's not working. Please could you reword your question, or use examples/images?

Comment: He means that when he swipes over to the mapview and moves around the map he swipes back to the other tab. he would like to disable this when on the mapview

Comment: yes Mr.Darryn. u guess exactly same which i want. please give me suggetion  how can i do that.